# How to pass the post parameter into .htm page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm trying the `post()` in ajax of jQuery; I learnt the parameter can be passed using `post()`, but I didn't know how to handle them in the respective html page. Can someone help me do it?

Here is my code for `post()`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    debugger;
        $.post("postpage.htm",
        {
                name: "John Doe",
                age: "40"
        },
        function(data, textStatus)
        {
            alert("ur status is:" + textStatus);
            alert("Response from server: " + data);
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for postpage.html..

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Now in posted page...!!
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>"<name>'s age is <age>"</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Yeah you need to post it somewhere. What are you expecting your post to do? You want to get back the HTML page with the filled in variables? If that is what you want that there is not really need for server side script but not a POST call either.

Comment: Do you get this error in your console: 'Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'? Online the `$.get` works fine but locally it might have that error.

Comment: Try to put it online or on a localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need server side script for that but not a POST either. Just use get and string replace.

Something like :

```
$(function(){
    var name = "John Doe";
    var age = "42";
    $.get("postpage.html", function(data, textStatus){
        data = data.replace('##name##',name);
        data = data.replace('##age##',age);
        alert("ur status is:" + textStatus);
        alert("Response from server: " + data);
    });
});
```

And your postpage.html would look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Now in posted page...!!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>##name##'s age is ##age##</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your 'postpage.html' exist? Can you make a Fiddle? Tried it here and it works.

Comment: hEY ofCOURSE YES... I jus tried changing its name from "postpage.html" to "getpage.html" (its 'get' method na..!!!) and also changed respectively in my "$.get("getpage.html", function(data, textStatus)" line....!!! But stil...?? Why it isnt working for me??...

Comment: What does your code look like now? Can you update your question?

Comment: An answer and a question can have upvotes and downvotes. My answer had a downvote. I was just questioning the person who gave me a downvote to ask him / her what is wrong with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [server-side scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting).

Imagine this:

1. You sending POST data to the server
2. Server having no logic to process the data, therefore it only serves you **static** HTML page you have in "postpage.html"

If you had eg. PHP on the server you send a POST data to the server and then have a script like yours just like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Now in posted page...!!
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><?php echo $_POST['name'] . "'s age is " . $_POST['age']; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This dynamically reads data from POST request and puts them into the HTML page and only then serves HTML page to the user.

Comment: Oh... then you say its not possible to use the post() without server-side script?... Is it like that?...

Comment: Only noticed this now :) without a server-side script there is nothing to process your POST data on the server so it's pointless sending them there.